# How to auto scale plot

Tags: plotting

I have this large equation involving the variables x, y and I need to plot it with all its important features. How? Is there an auto fit/zoom feature?

```
25448251500000 - 535526010000 x + 5077310000 x^2 - 36775800 x^3 + 
  250890 x^4 - (6199 x^5)/5 + (17 x^6)/5 - x^7/250 + 920347020000 y - 
  16448410100 x y + 122367000 x^2 y - 607718 x^3 y + (15694 x^4 y)/
  5 - (7099 x^5 y)/500 + (9 x^6 y)/250 - (x^7 y)/25000 + 
  15128205050 y^2 - 220083300 x y^2 + 1275939 x^2 y^2 - (
  19598 x^3 y^2)/5 + (8699 x^4 y^2)/1000 - (11 x^5 y^2)/500 + (
  x^6 y^2)/50000 + 152047500 y^3 - 1691358 x y^3 + 7640 x^2 y^3 - (
  96 x^3 y^3)/5 + (13 x^4 y^3)/500 - (x^5 y^3)/25000 + 1032409 y^4 - (
  40191 x y^4)/5 + (119 x^2 y^4)/5 - (11 x^3 y^4)/250 + (x^4 y^4)/
  50000 + (24094 y^5)/5 - (12299 x y^5)/500 + (9 x^2 y^5)/250 - (
  x^3 y^5)/25000 + (14699 y^6)/1000 - (23 x y^6)/500 + (x^2 y^6)/
  50000 + (13 y^7)/500 - (x y^7)/25000 + y^8/50000 + 
  5089650300000 Sin[x] - 107105202000 x Sin[x] + 
  1015462000 x^2 Sin[x] - 7355160 x^3 Sin[x] + 50178 x^4 Sin[x] - 
  6199/25 x^5 Sin[x] + 17/25 x^6 Sin[x] - (x^7 Sin[x])/1250 + 
  133172901000 y Sin[x] - 2218630000 x y Sin[x] + 
  14318780 x^2 y Sin[x] - 47992 x^3 y Sin[x] + 6299/50 x^4 y Sin[x] - 
  9/25 x^5 y Sin[x] + (x^6 y Sin[x])/2500 + 1693912000 y^2 Sin[x] - 
  21830360 x y^2 Sin[x] + 112000 x^2 y^2 Sin[x] - 
  304 x^3 y^2 Sin[x] + 12/25 x^4 y^2 Sin[x] - (x^5 y^2 Sin[x])/1250 + 
  13470380 y^3 Sin[x] - 119968 x y^3 Sin[x] + 408 x^2 y^3 Sin[x] - 
  4/5 x^3 y^3 Sin[x] + (x^4 y^3 Sin[x])/2500 + 71778 y^4 Sin[x] - 
  10199/25 x y^4 Sin[x] + 17/25 x^2 y^4 Sin[x] - (x^3 y^4 Sin[x])/
  1250 + 12299/50 y^5 Sin[x] - 21/25 x y^5 Sin[x] + (x^2 y^5 Sin[x])/
  2500 + 12/25 y^6 Sin[x] - (x y^6 Sin[x])/1250 + (y^7 Sin[x])/2500 ==
  0
```

Answer (score 2):

Not a complete answer but note that if we take your equation and then simplify we get

```
eqn = 25448251500000 - 535526010000 x + 5077310000 x^2 - 
    36775800 x^3 + 250890 x^4 - (6199 x^5)/5 + (17 x^6)/5 - x^7/250 + 
    920347020000 y - 16448410100 x y + 122367000 x^2 y - 
    607718 x^3 y + (15694 x^4 y)/5 - (7099 x^5 y)/500 + (9 x^6 y)/
     250 - (x^7 y)/25000 + 15128205050 y^2 - 220083300 x y^2 + 
    1275939 x^2 y^2 - (19598 x^3 y^2)/5 + (8699 x^4 y^2)/
     1000 - (11 x^5 y^2)/500 + (x^6 y^2)/50000 + 152047500 y^3 - 
    1691358 x y^3 + 
    7640 x^2 y^3 - (96 x^3 y^3)/5 + (13 x^4 y^3)/500 - (x^5 y^3)/
     25000 + 1032409 y^4 - (40191 x y^4)/5 + (119 x^2 y^4)/
     5 - (11 x^3 y^4)/250 + (x^4 y^4)/50000 + (24094 y^5)/
     5 - (12299 x y^5)/500 + (9 x^2 y^5)/250 - (x^3 y^5)/
     25000 + (14699 y^6)/1000 - (23 x y^6)/500 + (x^2 y^6)/
     50000 + (13 y^7)/500 - (x y^7)/25000 + y^8/50000 + 
    5089650300000 Sin[x] - 107105202000 x Sin[x] + 
    1015462000 x^2 Sin[x] - 7355160 x^3 Sin[x] + 50178 x^4 Sin[x] - 
    6199/25 x^5 Sin[x] + 17/25 x^6 Sin[x] - (x^7 Sin[x])/1250 + 
    133172901000 y Sin[x] - 2218630000 x y Sin[x] + 
    14318780 x^2 y Sin[x] - 47992 x^3 y Sin[x] + 
    6299/50 x^4 y Sin[x] - 9/25 x^5 y Sin[x] + (x^6 y Sin[x])/2500 + 
    1693912000 y^2 Sin[x] - 21830360 x y^2 Sin[x] + 
    112000 x^2 y^2 Sin[x] - 304 x^3 y^2 Sin[x] + 
    12/25 x^4 y^2 Sin[x] - (x^5 y^2 Sin[x])/1250 + 
    13470380 y^3 Sin[x] - 119968 x y^3 Sin[x] + 408 x^2 y^3 Sin[x] - 
    4/5 x^3 y^3 Sin[x] + (x^4 y^3 Sin[x])/2500 + 71778 y^4 Sin[x] - 
    10199/25 x y^4 Sin[x] + 
    17/25 x^2 y^4 Sin[x] - (x^3 y^4 Sin[x])/1250 + 
    12299/50 y^5 Sin[x] - 
    21/25 x y^5 Sin[x] + (x^2 y^5 Sin[x])/2500 + 
    12/25 y^6 Sin[x] - (x y^6 Sin[x])/1250 + (y^7 Sin[x])/2500 == 0;


eqn1=FullSimplify[eqn]
```

> (-300 + 2 x - y) (24950 + (-300 + x) x + 
>           y (100 + y)) (1699950000 + (-200 + x) x (20000 + (-200 + x) x) + 
>           y (400 + y) (80000 + y (400 + y))) (100 + y + 20 Sin[x]) == 0

Which is easier to work with. Further we can find solutions for y as follows

```
sols = Solve[eqn1, y]
```

> ```
> {{y -> 2 (-150 + x)},
>   {y -> -50 - Sqrt[-22450 + 300 x - x^2]},
>   {y -> -50 +  Sqrt[-22450 + 300 x - x^2]}, 
>   {y -> -200 - (-99950000 + 4000000 x - 60000 x^2 + 
>           400 x^3 - x^4)^(1/4)}, {y -> -200 - 
>         I (-99950000 + 4000000 x - 60000 x^2 + 400 x^3 - x^4)^(1/4)},
>   {y -> -200 + I (-99950000 + 4000000 x - 60000 x^2 + 400 x^3 - x^4)^(1/4)}, 
>   {y -> -200 + (-99950000 + 4000000 x - 60000 x^2 + 400 x^3 - x^4)^(1/4)},
>   {y -> -20 (5 + Sin[x])}}
> ```

showing that there are seven solutions. Two of which are very simple. Further the original equation may be factored.

```
Factor[eqn1]
```

> (-300 + 2 x - y)
>    (24950 - 300 x + x^2 + 100 y + y^2)
>    (1699950000 -  4000000 x + 60000 x^2 - 400 x^3 + x^4 + 32000000 y + 240000 y^2 + 
>           800 y^3 + y^4)
>    (100 + y + 20 Sin[x]) == 0

Showing that you have a straight line, a circle, a sine wave and a further contour for which I don't have a name.   Bob Hanlon illustrates them nicely. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell Mathematica the region for which you have an interest.

```
ContourPlot[
 25448251500000 - 535526010000 x + 5077310000 x^2 - 36775800 x^3 + 
   250890 x^4 - (6199 x^5)/5 + (17 x^6)/5 - x^7/250 + 920347020000 y - 
   16448410100 x y + 122367000 x^2 y - 
   607718 x^3 y + (15694 x^4 y)/5 - (7099 x^5 y)/500 + (9 x^6 y)/
    250 - (x^7 y)/25000 + 15128205050 y^2 - 220083300 x y^2 + 
   1275939 x^2 y^2 - (19598 x^3 y^2)/5 + (8699 x^4 y^2)/1000 - (11 x^5 y^2)/
    500 + (x^6 y^2)/50000 + 152047500 y^3 - 1691358 x y^3 + 
   7640 x^2 y^3 - (96 x^3 y^3)/5 + (13 x^4 y^3)/500 - (x^5 y^3)/25000 + 
   1032409 y^4 - (40191 x y^4)/5 + (119 x^2 y^4)/5 - (11 x^3 y^4)/
    250 + (x^4 y^4)/50000 + (24094 y^5)/5 - (12299 x y^5)/500 + (9 x^2 y^5)/
    250 - (x^3 y^5)/25000 + (14699 y^6)/1000 - (23 x y^6)/500 + (x^2 y^6)/
    50000 + (13 y^7)/500 - (x y^7)/25000 + y^8/50000 + 5089650300000 Sin[x] - 
   107105202000 x Sin[x] + 1015462000 x^2 Sin[x] - 7355160 x^3 Sin[x] + 
   50178 x^4 Sin[x] - 6199/25 x^5 Sin[x] + 
   17/25 x^6 Sin[x] - (x^7 Sin[x])/1250 + 133172901000 y Sin[x] - 
   2218630000 x y Sin[x] + 14318780 x^2 y Sin[x] - 47992 x^3 y Sin[x] + 
   6299/50 x^4 y Sin[x] - 9/25 x^5 y Sin[x] + (x^6 y Sin[x])/2500 + 
   1693912000 y^2 Sin[x] - 21830360 x y^2 Sin[x] + 112000 x^2 y^2 Sin[x] - 
   304 x^3 y^2 Sin[x] + 12/25 x^4 y^2 Sin[x] - (x^5 y^2 Sin[x])/1250 + 
   13470380 y^3 Sin[x] - 119968 x y^3 Sin[x] + 408 x^2 y^3 Sin[x] - 
   4/5 x^3 y^3 Sin[x] + (x^4 y^3 Sin[x])/2500 + 71778 y^4 Sin[x] - 
   10199/25 x y^4 Sin[x] + 17/25 x^2 y^4 Sin[x] - (x^3 y^4 Sin[x])/1250 + 
   12299/50 y^5 Sin[x] - 21/25 x y^5 Sin[x] + (x^2 y^5 Sin[x])/2500 + 
   12/25 y^6 Sin[x] - (x y^6 Sin[x])/1250 + (y^7 Sin[x])/2500 == 0,
 {x, -50, 250}, {y, -225, -25},
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 MaxRecursion -> 2,
 AspectRatio -> 200/300]
```

[image]